# SpriteKit physics strange behavior

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a strange behavior in my game using SpriteKit and SKSphysicbody.
There is the object A (the yellow one in the images at the bottom of the post) that push the object B (the brown square).
So, when the object A reach the center of the screen it stop to move.
This happens in all directions (bottom to top, top to bottom, right to left and left to right) and only at the center of the screen, but not happens if the object A is a little bit shift from the center of the screen.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

**Case 002:**

[image: Case 002]

**Case 003:**

[image: Case 003]

Comment: Are you using collision bit masks?

Comment: Yes. I use collision bit masks.